# Mypy is not able to find an attribute defined in the parent NamedTuple

Tags: python, mypy

In my project I'm using [Fava](https://github.com/beancount/fava). Fava, is using [Beancount](https://github.com/beancount/beancount). I have configured `Mypy` to read the stubs locally by setting `mypy_path` in `mypy.ini`. `Mypy` is able to read the config. So far so good.

Consider this function of mine

```py
1 def get_units(postings: list[Posting]):
2    numbers = []
3    for posting in postings:
4        numbers.append(posting.units.number)
5    return numbers
```

When I run `mypy src` I get the following error

```bash
report.py:4 error: Item "type" of "Union[Amount, Type[MISSING]]" has no attribute "number"  [union-attr]
```

When I check the defined stub [here](https://github.com/beancount/fava/blob/a0fb2c8219c33dd3811628ad27d9239e1f330872/stubs/beancount/core/data.pyi#L70) I can see the type of `units` which is `Amount`. Now, `Amount` is inheriting `number` from its parent [`_Amount`](https://github.com/beancount/beancount/blob/d8a45f5e465b8af65adf3aba60eb167f097bcb6a/beancount/core/amount.py#L26). Going back to the stubs in `Fava` I can see the type [here](https://github.com/beancount/fava/blob/a0fb2c8219c33dd3811628ad27d9239e1f330872/stubs/beancount/core/amount.pyi#L9).

My question is why `mypy` is not able to find the attribute `number` although it is defined in the stubs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type of `units` isn't `Amount`:

```
class Posting(NamedTuple):
    account: Account
    units: Union[Amount, Type[MISSING]]
```

It's `Union[Amount, Type[MISSING]]`, *exactly like the error message says*.  And if it's `Type[MISSING]` there is no `number` attribute, *exactly like the error message says*.  If you were to run this code and `units` were in fact `MISSING`, it would raise an `AttributeError` on trying to access that `number` attribute.

(Aside: I'm not familiar with `beancount`, but this seems like a weird interface to me -- the more idiomatic thing IMO would be to just make it an `Optional[Amount]` with `None` representing the "missing" case.)

You need to change your code to account for the `MISSING` possibility so that `mypy` knows you're aware of it (and also so that readers of your code can see that possibility before it bites them in the form of an `AttributeError`).  Something like:

```
for posting in postings:
    assert isinstance(posting.units, Amount), "Units are MISSING!"
    numbers.append(posting.units.number)
```

Obviously if you want your code to do something other than raise an `AssertionError` on `MISSING` `units`, you should write your code to do that instead of `assert`.

If you want to just assume that it's an `Amount` and raise an `AttributeError` at runtime if it's not, use `typing.cast` to tell mypy that you want to consider it to be an `Amount` even though the type stub says otherwise:

```
for posting in postings:
    # posting.units might be MISSING, but let's assume it's not
    numbers.append(cast(Amount, posting.units).number)
```

Comment: Probably, `None` is a valid attribute value, and `MISSING` is a dedicated object created as a sentinel to indicate a truly missing value for `units`.

Comment: If `None` is a valid value, the module's implementation is invalidating its public interface (`Amount` is an actual class, it's not a type alias that includes `None`), which is even worse than just having a weird interface.

Comment: If you are interested why they have it. From the source, [MISSING](https://github.com/beancount/beancount/blob/master/beancount/core/number.py#L29): 
_A constant used to make incomplete data, e.g. missing numbers in the cost spec
to be filled in automatically. We define this as a class so that it appears in
errors that would occur from attempts to access incomplete data._

Comment: Yeah, I get what they're trying to do, but `None` works exactly the same way and is much less awkward.  :)  I'm guessing they came up with the interface before type annotations were a thing and they wanted a way to signal "no really, we didn't just forget a return statement".